# Generar Reporte en PDF Utilizando C# y Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Necesito generar un reporte en PDF. Actualmente utilizo reportviewer como herramienta pero es lento por lo que necesito utilizar otra complemento que me recomiendan?

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Las preguntas pidiendo consejos y recomendaciones sobre herramientas se consideran demasiado amplias y basadas en opiniones y no entran bien en la temática del sitio. Además, completa el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo estoy empezando a usar la siguiente librería, está en JS ya que va desde el front, pero fijate que tiene buena documentacion.

http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/

Comment: Fijate q esa misma libreria habia investigado y si existe mucha documentación gracias